# text manipulation in shellscript

Tags: shell

I want to add a dot to all lines that doesn't start with a dot.  How can I do this in shellscript?  should I use sed?

```
example file:
.a
a
b
.c
```

turns to

```
.a
.a
.b
.c
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use sed:

```
sed -i '/^[^.]/s/^/./' text_file
```

Comment: can you explain the patterns a little?

Comment: `/^[^.]/` means "for every line that starts with a character that is not a period".  `s/^/./` means "replace the beginning of the line with a period".  The confusing thing is that `^` can mean two things: here it is used to anchor the search pattern to the beginning of a line, and it also used to negate a character class.  `[abc]` matches either `a` or `b` or `c`, while `[^abc]` matches anything that is *not* `a` or `b` or `c`.